# Kafka- How to automatically use the second cluster when the first cluster is down?

Tags: apache-kafka, mirroring

I am trying to replicate data from one to another kafka cluster by using mirror maker . Suppose if master cluster is down, is it possible to automatically send the kafka messages to the second cluster ? And also is it possible to  synchronise the cluster 1 with cluster 2 when the cluster 1 is up again automatically with less manual intervention?

any help is highly appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

**I think you meant to ask how to maintain copies between Kafka brokers, that together are considered to be a Kafka Cluster.**

**If that's the case**, it's pretty simple, all you have to do is configure a Kafka Cluster and to create a topic with replication factor with size that is equal to the size of the nodes in the Cluster.

**For example:**

Let's say that we want to have 3 Brokers on our Kafka Cluster, then you'll need to prepare for each broker a different configuration file, then startup them as a cluster, and then create a topic with replication factor of 3.

***Kafka will be responsible for maintaining the Fault Tolerance.***

For further info on actually do the configuration, watch these videos on youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDLPjuuYHxPbHdN8RXxrGdw

Comment: I am sorry u misunderstood it wrong. That is not the case btw. I have single cluster here spanning on multiple nodes , Currently i am running one broker instance on each of these nodes. I have a replication factor of 5 and it is perfectly alright. Suppose if entire cluster is down, I dont want to loose data/producers ,consumers to wait  .So, i am planning to replicate to another DC. Ultimately i want to increase availability for producers and consumers . Hope u understood the problem.